# External Interrupt Peripheral Microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller, voltage, current, gpio

I'm using this ATSAME53N20A-AU microcontroller - [Link](https://www.microchip.com/en-us/product/ATSAME53N20A)

I'd like to know what does the EIC and EXTINT peripherals would do?
So, I went through the Appnotes - [EXTINT](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/Atmel-42112-SAM-External-Interrupt-Driver-Extint_ApplicationNote_AT03246.pdf) and [EIC](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/Appnotes/Atmel-42278-SAM4L-External-Interrupt-Controller-EIC-Driver_ApplicationNote_AT07901.pdf)

I just want to know whether these peripherals will act as inputs or outputs?

No where I saw that these peripherals will be output. Can someone tell me whether these peripherals can be outputs? or only inputs?

Because, I am planning to use one pin for receiving interrupt from another device and one pin for generating reset to the other device? So, I want one pin to be input and other pin to be output.
So, whether EIC and EXTINT can be input as well as output if we configure?

Comment: But what would interrupt pins have to do with generating a reset pulse to another device?

Comment: EXTINT is an "external interrupt" that, by definition, is an input. A special input because it is detected quickly via interrupt. Read about input pins and interrupts.

Comment: Can you please tell me about EIC? And EXTINT is an input and cannot be an output right?

Comment: Can someone clarify this question ?

Comment: The EIC maps physical pins to specific interrupts. Your links are for the *drivers* that are available to take care of the low level controls required. Interrupts in this sense are inputs.

Comment: For your case, set up one of the available pins as an interrupt (input) and assert an (ordinary) output pin as a reset to the other device in the interrupt handler (a callback in the documentation).

Comment: You determine if the pin is input or output and whether it gets mapped to the EIC or other peripherals for that pin.